# Can the Facebook C# SDK support these typical site login/registration scenarios?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to support the following scenarios on my ASP.NET MVC website:

1. First time visitor wants to
   register, via facebook connect. I'd
   like the user to have an entry in my
   user membership table - so I have
   them enter a username/password
   (email gets populated via facebook
   connect).
2. Registered user returns to my
   site, logged into facebook already.
   I'd like my site to see they're
   logged into facebook already and
   auto log them into my membership
   system.
3. Registered user returns to my
   site, but is not logged into
   facebook. I'd like to give them two
   options: to log into my site
   directly or use facebook connect.

Extra:

1. After a user has connected their
   facebook account to my site, I'd
   like to use their facebook profile
   photo throughout my site where the
   user has participated.
2. I'd also like to post a bit of text, maybe even a photo, to the user's wall (when they perform an action of course).

Couple questions:

- What should I store to tie the user's id in my membership system to their facebook account? I'm assuming it would be their facebook user id.
- Can [this facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) handle these scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you would store their Facebook Id and Yes the API can support this.

Comment: Thank you, when you say "Yes the API can support this", do you mean the Facebook C# SDK can support this? Have you used the Facebook C# SDK before? What did you think of it? (sorry for the 20 questions... )

Comment: Yes and No, yes I've used it but before the current graph API.  The library supports "everything" and therefore will support your scenario.

Comment: @chad I wrote the sdk you are asking about and can tell you that your scenario is supported.

@jfar You are probably talking about the Facebook Developer Toolkit, which is different considering my sdk was not out before the Graph API.

Comment: @Nathan Totten - Great! This is my first foray into using/integrating facebook into a website. I'll have a great deal of questions at first, but I'm a fast learner. :) I was looking over codeplex & your blog, not a lot of code samples out there. Do you know of any besides the sample asp.net MVC sample on the codeplex site?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't much yet. If you have a question just post it on stackoverflow. I check here often for questions related to the SDK. We are working on more samples that should be up in the next couple weeks.